# Asynchronous loading of images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, lazy-loading

How can I load images asynchronously?  This is currently what I'm doing (borrowed from open source code for loading an image thumbnail):

```
- (UIImage*)thumbnailListView:(ThumbnailListView*)thumbnailListView
                 imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[recommendedArray objectAtIndex:index]] ;

//  [[cell grid_image] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]];



NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isImageLoaded = YES;
UIImage *bookImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, [[recommendedArray objectAtIndex:index] lastPathComponent]]];

if(bookImage == nil)
    isImageLoaded = NO;

if(!isImageLoaded){
    UIImage *thumbnailImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"App-icon-144x144.png"];}
else{
    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[recommendedArray objectAtIndex:index]]]]];
      return thumbnailImage;

}



}
```

I tried adding the following to the method, but it's producing an error for the NSURL:

```
dispatch_queue_t imageLoadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.g.load", NULL);

dispatch_async(imageLoadQueue, ^{
    //Wait for 5 seconds...
    usleep(1000000);

    NSArray *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    

    for(int k=0; k < [images count];k++){
        NSLog(@"Loading %d Image", k);
        NSString *imgURL = [images objectAtIndex:k];
        NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];
        [imgData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, [imgURL lastPathComponent]] atomically:YES];
    }

    [[self collectionView] reloadData];
    NSLog(@"DONE WITH ALL IMAGES");
});
```

error

```
[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12ea7240
2013-04-18 11:18:35.456 AssamKart[3084:14d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12ea7240'
```

Comment: use AsyncImageview Class files for it and also you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15377082/1713478 answer for download class files and for know how to implement.

Comment: What error is it producing?

Comment: I don't see any calls to `NSURL -length` in there. Are you sure the error is because of the above code?

Comment: @nil my mistake check the code now

Comment: THE EXCEPTION THROWING AT UIIMAGE *BOOKIMAGE line

Comment: This is still immensely confusing and .. it's not really clear how the first code block and the second code block are at all related, honestly.

Comment: the second code with dispath... are  inside VIEW DIDLOAD methode

Comment: @Naveen once just can u show me imgURL value?

Comment: i mean wt was the string value u r getting in imgURL@Naveen

Comment: its not goint into the "dispatch_async(imageLoadQueue, ^{" statement so its not executing that part

Comment: @Naveen jst hv alook on my ans and check like that

Comment: you can also use [this Special UIImageView](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/LazyImageView) to lazily download images

Answer (score 0):

Inside the method->

```
- (UIImage*)thumbnailListView:(ThumbnailListView*)thumbnailListView
                     imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

Use this->

```
NSURLConnection *aNSURLConnection= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:<#(NSURLRequest *)#> delegate:<#(id)#> startImmediately:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

and the inside the delegate

`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;`   get the image data and implement your logic and here u shall call again the

```
- (UIImage*)thumbnailListView:(ThumbnailListView*)thumbnailListView
                     imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

method recursively till your `recommendedArray` is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

just do like this,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    for (int k=0; k<[images count]; k++) {
    NSString *imgURL = [images objectAtIndex:k];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];
    [data writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, [imgURL lastPathComponent]] atomically:YES];

    }
});
```

Comment: instead of dispatch_async block in ur viewdidload

Comment: and let me know the value of imgURL

Comment: same exception ...and the execution not going into that dispatch its just exiting like condition false

Comment: once comment all the code in your viewDidLoad: method and use only   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"]];
 });

Comment: and check whether data is coming or not?

Comment: i think the probelm inside  - (UIImage*)thumbnailListView:(ThumbnailListView*)thumbnailListView
                 imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28411/discussion-between-murali-and-naveen)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for downloading ur images from the internet and use the method:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncImageView.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

```
AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Your Frame)];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
NSURL *URL =  [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:URL]];
[AsyncImageLoader defaultCache];
[[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader]loadImageWithURL:URL target:self success:@selector(successSelector) failure:@selector(failureSelector)];
```

Comment: You won't need to call this on a block manually...it will run asynchronously for you.