# Updating Tableview with photos in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, ios10

I'm currently hitting an API to get a list of inventory items.  Right now I am also downloading all of the photos for all of the items on initial load.  What I want to do is load the table view with all of the text (be able to interact with the tableview) and then load the photos in the background and update each row once the photo has been retrieved so that it loads faster.  I have all of the URLs of the photos from the API. How would I do this?

Comment: You have to implement lazy loading for your `UITableView`, Once the data is is ready, you should update the UITableView right away & for image loading you can use https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher type of libraries to lazy load the images on scrolling of table-view. Also follow the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694645/how-to-implement-lazy-loading-of-images-in-table-view-using-swift

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I've been looking for something like this for awhile

Comment: @ Prakash Donga Good work Prakash. but you should give your answer in answer section not in comment. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: you can use [Alamofire Images](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) its great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [Alamofire Image](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) for this purpose. Here is a sample code.

After installing its pod, you can do:

```
cell.yourImageView.af_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil,  imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.5), runImageTransitionIfCached: false, completion: {response in
                        // if you have activity indicator you can stop it when images is downloaded 
                        //cell.activityIdicator.stopAnimating()
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many sdk available for lazyloading. You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for same.

It will automatically load image into your UIImageView as soon as image download.