# DispatchQueue.main.async blocking the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been trying to create a photo gallery in Swift 3.0 and I want to load images stored in the document directory into the collection view asynchronously. I tried `DispatchQueue.main.async` but it blocks the main thread and freezes the app for a few seconds:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let identifier = "ImageCell"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    let url = self.imageURL[indexPath.row]
    cell.lazyLoadImage(from: url)
    return cell
}
```

And the ImageCell class:

```
class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    func lazyLoadImage(from url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path) {
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: If you pause the app while it's frozen, what's in the main thread's backtrace?

Comment: Actually you are doing nothing i mean you are in main thread and  also dispatch block in main thread

Comment: If the images are just files, I wouldn't have thought you would need to dispatch anything asynchronously; just load the image.  If your image files are really large, consider have thumbnails that load more quickly in your cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First switch to background thread and load image on it, and again switch to main thread and display image.

```
func lazyLoadImage(from url: URL) {
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
         if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path) {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.imageView.image = image
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: you also need to cancel previous task (if is running)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it completing wrong. In short, I can say that's not the "lazy loading". What you are doing is blocking the threads to download the content from the `URL` and load it to `UIImageView`. The thread will not be release until the download happens and you are using it in "reusable Cells" and that's obvious your application will stuck!

> Solution

There are many most popular libraries like [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage), [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) , [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). From which I am picking up "SDWebImage" and you can call load image in `async` way via following code:

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: url , placeholderImage: nil)
```

Also, please refer to this SO question ([how to implement lazy loading of images in table view using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694645/how-to-implement-lazy-loading-of-images-in-table-view-using-swift)) for more detail.