# How to async load images on dynamic UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, asynchronous

Now I have a custom cell with the image and label. Later I print these cells by:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCell

    var url = NSURL(string: postCover[indexPath.row])

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) { 
        cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }

    var title = postTitle[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellLabel.text = title

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

    return cell
}
```

and when I open an app and scroll it freezes. How can I fix this bug?

I read about it, that I must use async image loading in my tableView, but don't I load them async already?

I searched and think about it 4-5 days and nothing. Can anyone give me some tips, please?

Comment: use third party api AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: @DharmeshKheni what this line means - `et currentImage = deals[indexPath.row].imageID`? it prints the next error: `could'n find member imageID`

Comment: @muku I did install AFNetworking to my project. What I must to do for now? Can you help me?

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong/32601838#32601838

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule the downloading of image asynchronously for each cell using GCD as-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCell

    var url = NSURL(string: postCover[indexPath.row])

cell.imageView.image = nil;
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:parsedData[@"imageLR"]];

            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            if (image) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
                         cell.imageView.image = image;
                         [cell setNeedsLayout];
                     }
                 });
             }
        });

return cell
}
```

for Swift you can do so as

```
if let data = self.cache.objectForKey(urlString) as? NSData {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                cell.imageView.image = image;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Great, but could you please translate it to Swift?

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade, sure I'll do that

Comment: This will not cache image and as user scroll the data will download again ... use SDWebImage , that will do both downloading and caching

Comment: The problem the approach is there is no caching, so the cell image loads every time when the table is scrolled. Use a cache policy or SDWebimageCache library to solve this.

Comment: for table view's with few cells you can use above approach, also for downloading image only once you can save the downloaded image in dictionary for url as key, and if you need caching than as suggested by all, use SDWebImage

Answer (score 2):

You can use third part Library [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) on gitHub . It`s base on Objective-C, and there is another Library [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) which base on Swift. And maybe this is what you want.

Comment: KingFisher is really simple and straigthforward. But I have one question, what is the cleanest way to refresh your cell after kingfisher finish the download? Do you have to set a callback and call .reloadRowsAtIndexPath?

Answer (score -1):

create a bridging header in swift.Import AFNetworking header files

and then find these method setImageWithURLRequest

`cell.imageView.setImageWithURLRequest` you can call in these way

Comment: can you help me chat, please?