# UITableView displaying webImages in Swift languages seems to freeze

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, webimage

so i'm kind of a noobe to iOS and Swift also (actually only one month and a half). So I'm trying to make a tableview displaying some images coming from the web, I managed to get the correct info from a web API and display them in the tableview. But, the tableview with online images seems to freeze, I should wait 2-3 seconds for it to move just a little bit and freeze again, which is very frustrating.
I know it has something to do with synchronize, I also tried `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){}`, and since I'm developing with Swift not ObJ, I tried an open source Web Image download helper from Github called Kingfisher, but it didn't solve my problem.
So, please, help me, and thanks.
To keep it simple, here's the **demo code**:

```
var arrays = [
"NPWR02174_00_013F09F4AE3D70230FA695261A8E994D275DF62333/C878A05EF327D7D42E2AF5E1EE15672A1509962C.PNG",
"NPWR04270_00_01C53CAC0BACAC6F052AE4B968370CF9B899DDA81E/C1E1A8AD62EDE2FB95C3BD562F2783F157A0D011.PNG",
"NPWR04472_00_01CB90FF28A2EBB55D210932F56935B377E7A28ECB/DCA2F66365777A7330F685CD8CD5F90F2FE62671.PNG",
"NPWR04841_00_017B982A2A44BB607DECD77484C4670CCB505B65E4/91824E16D16C2789CC34A2F5F5444CD30D71C8F1.PNG",
"NPWR05212_00_018ADD99CEA95C240EFDC92FB993F6BC8C0AF7904D/7266E29159EE69D31AA24FB94BC0E90F5306774A.PNG",
"NPWR05254_00_015EB28BB38A5580D6A73CA0BDFB2F8C6864F85F66/76ED779ECE98E63E8A1A229AE626F62E8325D703.PNG",
"NPWR05257_00_01CB48AFF2A9F0795B5569E1DABBC612E3FA13B79A/3524288D6B1E5B4F51CF7DEA4A3E621913A1BA8C.PNG",
"NPWR05326_00_01DF67B968910B06FDABD8A2C2C6AAB72E0DD47048/8AB6EC3EC992C35472F02DD0C8D4122302C802E1.PNG",
"NPWR05401_00_0188285B6025E65909B39E295D2542DF589EDCCC38/620822A98E3CFC1CFB3B5EDCF3F00B19A5B328C2.PNG",
]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrays.count

}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("gameCell")!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        let image = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView

    let imageString = arrays[indexPath.row] as! String

    let imageURL = NSURL(string: "https://trophy01.np.community.playstation.net/trophy/np/"+imageString)!

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)!

        image.image = UIImage(data: data)}

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Try using alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire or AlamofireImage https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Comment: I tried to use another open source project called Kingfisher, it's a swift version of SDWebImage, and it doesn't work, so i guess there's a problem with my own code.

Comment: So I tried Alamofire, and I used Alamofire.request(.GET,URL).responseJSON() {
            (request, response, result) in to get the JSON result and successfully display them in my tableview, BUT... the table view still freezes! I did try EVERY possible methods, maybe there's something about async in the Alamofire that i didn't use? Please help me.

Comment: remove the async dispatch

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are downloading the image synchronously. This is the code line that does so.

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)
```

Try downloading the image asynchronously and then update the cell once image is downloaded. Checkout this answer [How to async load images on dynamic UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389261/how-to-async-load-images-on-dynamic-uitableview)

Comment: so i changed my code as follows:dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        image.image = UIImage(data: data)}
        } It does load pictures super fast and not freezing again, but there's a new problem, overtime i scroll, new pictures show up in the same cell...very weird

Comment: You will need to implement the image caching mechanism so that you do not re-download the image which you have already downloaded.

For this, 
> create a mutable collection ( array or dictionary ) 
> Once an image is downloaded, add it to your collection and update the cell image 
> Put an “If-else" in "cellForRowAtIndexPath:” where you need to check first if the image is already present in collection. If yes then update the image with cache else download the image.