# iOS7: Multi-UITableview rendering lag

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsoperationqueue

I have a `viewcontroller` in a `universal` app which has 5 coloumns (`UITableview`). Initially I fetch data from `CoreData` and then categorise it in 5 `NSArrays`. After that I call all 5 `UITableViews` to reload via following code.

```
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [_tvLeftMost reloadData];
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [_tvLeft reloadData];
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [_tvCenter reloadData];
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [_tvRight reloadData];
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [_tvRightMost reloadData];
    }];
```

on both `IOS7&8(iPAD3)` the data is fetched in 0.5 secs. But reload tables takes 5 secs on `iOS8` and 20+ secs on `iOS7`. The `UITableView's` cell are not complex and only involve a local `UIImage` & a `UILabel`. How can I decrease rendering time on `iOS7`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload your UITableView in below way -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

If your UITableView load image from web url , then it must be async image loading. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong) tutorial for async image loading.

Comment: Tried that too. problem is that there are 5 of them. single table reload is no problem. Also dispatch_async with main queue is kind of same to adding operations on main NSOperationQueue's main queue.

Comment: you should keep your code in dispatch_async for load label and image in cellForRowAtIndexPath