# Does NSURLSession Take place in a separate thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I was designing an app that uses NSURLSession and thinking about putting it in a different thread with Grand Central Dispatch, but if NSURLSession automatically does that in the background, I wouldn't have to use GCD then, correct?

So in other words, does NSURLSession automatically use Grand Central Dispatch in the background, so we don't have to worry about it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes,

NSURLSession (URLSession in Swift) does its work in a background thread. The download **ALWAYS** takes place asynchronously on a background thread.

---

### EDIT:

There is no reason to wrap your code that invokes `NSURLSession` (or `URLSession` in Swift 3 or later) in a GCD call.

---

You can control whether its completion methods are executed on a background thread or not by the queue you pass in in the `delegateQueue` parameter to the init method. If you pass in nil, it creates a (background thread) serial operation queue where your completion methods are called. If you pass in `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()` (`OperationQueue.mainQueue()` in recent versions of Swift) then your completion delegate methods/closures will be invoked on the main thread and you won't have to wrap UI calls in `dispatch_async()` calls to the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of an NSURLSession request:

```
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someURL]
      completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                          NSURLResponse *response,
                          NSError *error) {
        // handle response

  }] resume];
```

From the Documentation: "This method is intended as an alternative to the sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: method of NSURLConnection, with the added ability to support custom authentication and cancellation."
Short answer is: yes, NSURLSession will do background operations. You don't have to worry about this blocking your UI.

Comment: Your answer is about the deprecated NSURLConnection. But the question is about NSURLSession.

Comment: Updated my answer to NSURLSession

Comment: Background operations are a different thing. `NSURLSession` always uses a background thread to transfer your data from the remote device. When the docs on `NSURLSession` talk about background, they are talking about having your download/data task continue even if your app is in the background, suspended, or even terminated.