# How to run bunch of tasks in background global queue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

In following code I want to send some values to server and also update badge number on Tabs. A chain of operatios are initiated from markRead() where I fetch values from server and once it is completed I update badge number on Tabs.

I feel this entire operation should be executed in background queue. I'm not sure how and where I shall send the task in background and then come back to main queue to update badge numbers.

Any help?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // I want to send following in the background queue
        self.markRead(senderId: self.psychicId)

        // Continue to do other stuff...

    }

    func markRead(senderId: Int) {

        fetchMarkRead(jsonObject: jsonObject) { (result, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            if (result?.success)! {
                self.updateBadges { () -> () in
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func markRead(jsonObject:[String:Any], _ completed: @escaping ((_ result: MarkAsReadRoot?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)) {

        // construct url, josn etc...

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completed( nil,error)
                return
            }
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                    completed( nil,"Error in getting data from server" as? Error)
                    return
            }

            do {
                let resultData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MarkAsReadRoot.self, from: data)
                completed( resultData,nil)
            } catch let jsonError {
                completed(nil,jsonError)
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func updateBadges(completed:@escaping (()->())){
        // Get values from server
        // Set badge number on Tabs
    }

}
```

Comment: No need to send `self.markRead(senderId: self.psychicId)` to background, just set badge number in  `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30855466/4311935

Comment: Ain't we already on the main thread when fetch from server (URLSession) is completed?

Comment: Nope, all UI update must be on main thread, read some Apple documentation. When you do UI update in URLSession completion Xcode will show you message that it must be on main.

Comment: Tx, I think I got it now.