# Async image loading after some actions on this image - image changes to wrong image while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know that there is similar question: [Async image loading from url inside a UITableView cell - image changes to wrong image while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong)

But I do not only load images from URL. I have them, perform some actions on them, and then assign them to `UIImageView` **WITHIN** `UITableViewCell`.

This is how I do this:

1. Within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

   ```
   cell.configureCellWithComment(comment)
   ```
2. These are methods inside my cell:

   ```
   func configureCellWithComment(comment: WLComment) {

       if let attachmentUrl = comment.attachmentUrl, let fileName = NSURL(string: attachmentUrl)?.lastPathComponent {

           if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(comment.destinationPathForAttachment().URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName).path!) {

               WLFileClient.sharedClient().downloadFileFrom(attachmentUrl, destinationPath: comment.destinationPathForAttachment(), fileName: fileName, progress: nil, completionBlock: { error in
                   self.attachImageToImageView()
               })
           } else {
               attachImageToImageView()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Private method:

```
private func attachImageToImageView() {

    if let attachmentUrl = comment.attachmentUrl, let fileName = NSURL(string: attachmentUrl)?.lastPathComponent {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

            let image = WLFileClient.sharedClient().previewImageForFileAtUrl(self.comment.destinationPathForAttachment().URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName))

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.previewAttachmentButton.enabled = true
                self.attachmentPreviewImageView.image = image
            });
        });
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `downloadFileFrom` is an asyc method. so by the time this task completes, the cell may have been reused for another row. so before you call `self.attachImageToImageView()`, check if the current cell is serving the same row as it was when the method started.

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the tag of the cell to the current row number.

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row
```

Now in your `configureCellWithComment` method, first store the tag into a variable and then check if the variable is still the same after the async task:

```
var tagCache:int = self.tag;

WLFileClient.sharedClient().downloadFileFrom(attachmentUrl, destinationPath: comment.destinationPathForAttachment(), fileName: fileName, progress: nil, completionBlock: {

    if(tagCache==self.tag)
      self.attachImageToImageView()
})
```

PS: I'm more used to Objective-C, not swift, so forgive syntax mistakes if any.

Comment: No problem about syntax, easily can apply to Swift. I need advice about async...:) Testing now...

Comment: Dont understand one thing. Why tag should be above `downloadFileFrom` instead of above `dispatch_async`?

Comment: There is no `dispatch_async` in `configureCellWithComment`