# TableView pattern for displaying multiple images from external URL

Tags: ios

I have a `ViewController` where I want a `UITableView` to contain 5-30 user profiles (name, profile pic, about me etc) it is one of the tabs in a `TabController`.  The profile content change rarely, but once a week, some profiles are added/removed.

The profile content comes in the form of a `json` object from our server that I parse into a `[[String:Anyobject]]` array.
One of the fields contain the URL to the profile picture (only like 30kb each).

**My question is:**  What is the best pattern for getting to the pictures and displaying them in the TV?

**First**, I am guessing it is preferable to do one single URL request, instead of 30 individual.  How can I accomplish that?  example URL to a profile image is:

```
www.example.com/assets/profileImages/useriD.png.
```

**Second**, should I save the pictures to CoreData first and then fetch them from there (if so how?) or should I just do a URL request inside the cell like I do to set the profile name etc ?

If anyone could point me in the right direction about the correct pattern for this that would be awesome, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your server has a scheme to do so, you can't get multiple images in a single request. You'll need to make one request per image (though iOS and the server should cooperate to maintain a single HTTP connection).

How you do caching is up to you, but:

- you can simply rely on iOS caching (provided the files have appropriate `Cache-Control`/`Expires` headers), possibly being a bit more insistent on cache use by setting the appropriate cache policy in your `NSURLRequest` (e.g. `ReturnCacheDataElseLoad`)
- you can add just a bit of local caching inside your app of the decoded images (`UIImage`). A simple `NSDictionary` inside your view controller should be enough
- you can store the images (encoded data) on disk. If you do so, instead of reinventing the wheel, you may want to use libraries such as [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). The docs of `SDWebImage` include numerous examples, including an UITableView example.
- you can store the images (encoded data) in Core Data, though their size does not make them ideal candidates for this.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very good answer, SDWebImage works unbelievably well.

Comment: Similar to SDWebImage, there is this swift library [https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift] witch has same functionalities.

Comment: SDWebImage is outdated at this point (still uses deprecated NSURLConnection etc). You might want to try some alternative [libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong/32601838#32601838)

Answer (score 1):

+1 for [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), that jcaron said. 
Its a really powerful tool. You can just simple add the url link in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for each `UIImage`, the rest is handled by the SDWebImage.
This lib downloads the images asynchronously, the performance is insane, and you can set the storing interval too.