# Images fluctuating on scroll in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, swift2

i am getting images from url's and displaying it in tableview which happens successfully but when i scroll it automatically and repeatedly changes but after i pause at that point for a couple of seconds (roughly 10 or more which is a pretty long time) the proper image loads.

```
func load_image(urlString:String)
    {
        let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil && data != nil)
            {
                func display_image()
                {
                    cell.pic.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
            }

        }

        task.resume()

    }
    load_image(urls[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: check this example it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam thanks it helped, initializing cell.pic.image = nil stopped the fluctuation of images but when i scroll back up the image disappears and loads again but in a comparatively lesser amount of time

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are You loading images in, I guess, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?
You can load it in `viewDidLoad` and store in some array. But if You need to do this as You are doing...

For better performance You can use `NSCache` to prevent loading images everytime tableview will show your cell. Try something like that:

```
let imageCache = NSCache()
func load_image(urlString:String)
{
    if let imageFromCache = imageCache.objectForKey(urlString) as? UIImage {
        cell.pic.image = imageFromCache
        return
    }
    let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil && data != nil)
        {
            func display_image()
            {
                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell.pic.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
        }

    }

    task.resume()

}
```

For more informations about NSCache you can check [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/).

Comment: i do load the images in cellForRowAt IndexPath but i retrieve the url from the database and store it in arrays in viewdidload. How would you recommend me doing it in viewDidLoad after retrieving the url itself ? I tried your suggested method, but images are still changing to one of the previous loaded images and changing back to the right one after few seconds.

Comment: Can You show Your code in `viewDidLoad` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

Your cell is being reused when scrolling. The `cellForRowAt` method will be called on scrolling.

Set `imageView.image = nil` in `cellForRowAt` method so no image will be display on the image view until they get downloaded.

We make `imageView.image = nil` is because if no image available for that cell then no image should be shown for that cell.