# JSON Image Parsing IOS Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, json, image, parsing, swift3

I'm totally new for iOS swift deveploment. I'm trying to do json image parsing with dynamic data/url, I tried without a result to search for examples for displaying data and images in table view or list view, can any one help me in achieving this task?

Here is the following link for image parsing

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt

Comment: Are you trying to load image inside cellforrow and set in tableview cell?...

Comment: Can you please share your code? you want to parse data ?  problem is not 100% understandable

Comment: Yes consuming json feed and displaying in table view

Comment: @Dheeraj D bro I'm basically android guy learning IOS trying to do json image parsing in ios using need a good example to learn json imge parsing

Comment: Try to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong

Comment: What you have done till now? Please share the code rather than link!

Answer (score 1):

As a newbie i think this Library will ease your most of the work,

- [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

the syntax is very dev friendly and simple , No struggling of `if let` syntax and nesting.Example usage create json with one simple line
`let json = JSON(data : data)` and many more with custom data types.Have a  look of this Lib

`let rank = json["worldpopulation"][0]["rank"].int
let country = json["worldpopulation"][0]["country"].string
let flag = json["worldpopulation"][0]["flag"].string`

Answer (score 0):

```
    func countriesResponseReceived(response : NSDictionary)
    {
        let arrCountries = (response.object(forKey: "worldpopulation")) as! NSArray

        for dict in arrCountries!
        {
            let dictData = dict as! NSDictionary
            let rank = dictData.object(forKey: "rank") as! NSInteger
            let country = dictData.object(forKey: "country") as! String
            let flag = dictData.object(forKey: "flag") as! String
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0
create new Xcode project
take one table view
create tableViewCell File
create NSObject Class File
take one lable(Country Name)
take one imageView(flag)
put Below Code in Right Place(note: place is mention before starting code)

ViewController Code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var imgTable: UITableView!
    var ArrayData:[Datad] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        service()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ArrayData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellDemo") as! ImageTableViewCell
        let objarr = ArrayData[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblContry.text = objarr.Country
     cell.imgflag.setImageFrom(imageURLString: objarr.Countryflag, completionHandler: { (complete, image, error) in
        })
        return cell

    }
    func service()
    {
       let url = URL(string: "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt")
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, errorresponce) in

            if errorresponce != nil
            {
                print(errorresponce?.localizedDescription ?? "Value Not Found")
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    if let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            for datacon in (dictionary.value(forKey: "worldpopulation") as! NSArray)                        {

                                let cellonr = Datad(dictionary: datacon as! NSDictionary )

                                self.ArrayData.append(cellonr)
                                self.imgTable.reloadData()

                            }

                        }

                                           }
                    else
                    {
                        print("value not found")
                    }

                }
                catch let error as Error!
                {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

TableView Cell Code

```
import UIKit

class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var lblContry: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var imgflag: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

NSObject File

```
import UIKit

class Datad: NSObject {

    var Country:String!
    var Countryflag:String!
    init(dictionary:NSDictionary)
    {
        Country =  (dictionary.value(forKey: "country") as! String)
        Countryflag =  (dictionary.value(forKey: "flag") as! String)

    }

}
```

copy this two file (Note below 2 File Name Not Change Strikly Follow ) first

ImageDownloadManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

typealias DownloadHandler = (_ success: Bool,  _ image: UIImage?,  _ error: Error?) -> Void
typealias DownloadProgressHandler = (_ totalBytesExpected : Int64,  _ bytesDownloaded: Int64, _ error : Error?) -> Void

private var kImageURLKey : String = "imageURLKey"

extension UIImageView{

    var imageURLId : String{

        get{
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kImageURLKey) as! String
        }
        set(newValue){
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kImageURLKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    func setImageFrom(imageURLString : String,
                      placeHolderImage: UIImage? = nil,
                      completionHandler: DownloadHandler?) {

        if (imageURLString.characters.count > 0){

            if ((placeHolderImage) != nil){
                self.image = placeHolderImage;
            }

            self.imageURLId = imageURLString

            ImageDownloadManager.sharedManager.getImageFromURL(imageURLString: imageURLString)
            { (success : Bool, image : UIImage?, error :Error?) in

                if (success){
                    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self.updateImage(image: image!, imageUrl: imageURLString)
                }

                if ((completionHandler) != nil){
                    completionHandler!(success, image, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func setImageFrom(imageURLString : String,
                      placeHolderImage: UIImage? = nil,
                      progressHandler: @escaping DownloadProgressHandler,
                      completionHandler: DownloadHandler?) {

        if (imageURLString.characters.count > 0){

            if ((placeHolderImage) != nil){
                self.image = placeHolderImage;
            }

            self.imageURLId = imageURLString


            ImageDownloadManager.sharedManager.getImageFromURL(imageURLString: imageURLString,
                                                               progessHandler: { (expectedBytes:Int64, downloadedBytes:Int64, error:Error?) in
                                                                if error != nil {
                                                                    completionHandler!(false, nil, error)
                                                                }else{
                                                                    progressHandler(expectedBytes, downloadedBytes, nil)
                                                                }


            },
                                                               completionHandler: {  (success:Bool, image:UIImage?, error:Error?) in

                                                                if (success){
                                                                    self.updateImage(image: image!, imageUrl: imageURLString)
                                                                }

                                                                if ((completionHandler) != nil){
                                                                    completionHandler!(success, image, error)
                                                                }
            })
        }

    }

    private func updateImage(image:UIImage, imageUrl:String) {

        if (imageUrl == imageURLId)
        {
            UIView.transition(with: self,
                              duration: 0.4,
                              options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                              animations: {
                                self.image = image;
            },
                              completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

UIImageView+AsyncLoad.swift

```
import UIKit


struct ImageDownloadInfo {
    let downloadURLString : String
    let downloadTask : URLSessionTask
    let progressHandler : DownloadProgressHandler?
    let completionHandler : DownloadHandler?
}

class ImageDownloadManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedManager : ImageDownloadManager = ImageDownloadManager()

    var imageLoaderQueue : [String:ImageDownloadInfo] = [:]
    var imageCache : NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = NSCache()

    lazy var downloadsSession : URLSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    lazy var downloadDelegateSession : URLSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: sharedManager, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    func getImageFromURL(imageURLString:String,
                         completionHandler:@escaping DownloadHandler) {

        let cachedImage : UIImage? = imageCache.object(forKey: imageURLString as NSString)

        if cachedImage != nil {
            completionHandler(true, cachedImage, nil)
        }else {
            downloadImageFor(imageURLString: imageURLString, downloadHandler: completionHandler)
        }
    }

    func getImageFromURL(imageURLString:String,
                         progessHandler: @escaping DownloadProgressHandler,
                         completionHandler: @escaping DownloadHandler ){
        let cachedImage : UIImage? = imageCache.object(forKey: imageURLString as NSString)

        if cachedImage != nil {
            progessHandler(1, 1, nil)
            completionHandler(true, cachedImage, nil)
        }else {
            downloadImageFor(imageURLString: imageURLString, progressHandler: progessHandler, completionHandler:completionHandler)
        }
    }

    private func downloadImageFor(imageURLString:String,
                                  downloadHandler: @escaping DownloadHandler) {


        var imageDownloadInfo: ImageDownloadInfo? = imageLoaderQueue[imageURLString]

        if imageDownloadInfo == nil {

            let imageLoaderTask = downloadsSession.dataTask(with: URL(string: imageURLString)!, completionHandler: { (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                    if (error != nil){
                        downloadHandler(false, nil, error)
                    }
                    else{
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        if image != nil {
                            ImageDownloadManager.sharedManager.imageCache.setObject(image!, forKey: imageURLString as NSString)
                            downloadHandler(true, image, nil)
                        }
                        else {
                            downloadHandler(false, nil, error)
                        }
                    }
                    ImageDownloadManager.sharedManager.imageLoaderQueue[imageURLString] = nil
                })
            })

            imageDownloadInfo = ImageDownloadInfo(downloadURLString: imageURLString,
                                                  downloadTask: imageLoaderTask,
                                                  progressHandler: nil,
                                                  completionHandler:nil)

            imageLoaderQueue[imageURLString] = imageDownloadInfo
            imageDownloadInfo?.downloadTask.resume()
        }
    }

    private func downloadImageFor(imageURLString:String,
                                  progressHandler: @escaping DownloadProgressHandler,
                                  completionHandler: @escaping DownloadHandler) {

        var imageDownloadInfo: ImageDownloadInfo? = imageLoaderQueue[imageURLString]

        if imageDownloadInfo == nil {

            let imageLoaderTask = downloadDelegateSession.downloadTask(with: URL(string: imageURLString)!)

            imageDownloadInfo = ImageDownloadInfo(downloadURLString: imageURLString,
                                                  downloadTask: imageLoaderTask,
                                                  progressHandler: progressHandler,
                                                  completionHandler:completionHandler)

            imageLoaderQueue[imageURLString] = imageDownloadInfo
            imageDownloadInfo?.downloadTask.resume()
        }

    }
}

extension ImageDownloadManager : URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

        let imageUrl : String = (downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString)!
        let imageDownloadInfo: ImageDownloadInfo? = imageLoaderQueue[imageUrl]

        if imageDownloadInfo != nil {


            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: location)

                let image = UIImage(data: data)

                ImageDownloadManager.sharedManager.imageCache.setObject(image!, forKey: imageUrl as NSString)

                if let completionHandler = imageDownloadInfo?.completionHandler {

                    completionHandler(true, image, nil)
                }

            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){

        let imageUrl = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString
        let imageDownloadInfo: ImageDownloadInfo? = imageLoaderQueue[imageUrl!]

        if imageDownloadInfo != nil {

            if let progressHandler = imageDownloadInfo?.progressHandler {
                progressHandler(totalBytesExpectedToWrite, totalBytesWritten, nil)
            }
        }
    }

}
```