# Display image in cell.imageView.image using URL

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to display image once it's been processed.
Here's my code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodList", for: indexPath)
        let dict = itemsArray?[indexPath.row]


        cell.textLabel?.text = dict?["food_name"] as? String
        var URLz = dict?["image_url"] as! String
        Alamofire.request(URLz).response{ response in
            if let data = response.data{
                let image = UIImage(data:data)
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            }else{
                print("Data is nil.")
            }
        }





        return cell;
    }
```

When I do the following; nothing gets displayed but table rows.

Comment: You should use https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage , install via pods and just  do `imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)`

Comment: `cell.imageView?.image = image` should be done in mainthread, but as suggested by others Alamofire has an "extension" for images: AlamofireImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong) to download and show image in tableviewcell, you need to check if the cell is visible before assigning the image to the imageview.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodList", for: indexPath)
            .............
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png") //or nil
            if let dict = dict, imageURL = dict["image_url"] as? String {
                Alamofire.request(imageURL).response { response in
                    if let data = response.data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                                 cell.imageView?.image = image
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Data is nil.")
                    }
                }
            }
            return cell
    }
```

Better option would be to use third party libraries like [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) which uses UIImageView extension to download and cache images from the network. It would as simple as below

```
let url = URL(string: imageURL)!
cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly as expected! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Give a try to Kingfisher as well it's a better option.