# Loading Image from URL iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to load an image from an image URL. All the code I have researched and tried finds a few errors, a lot having to do with new ARC compatibility.

I need the image to load into an image view.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Code that you've tried?

Comment: you'll need to post some code that you've already tried and tell us what errors you are getting

Comment: Check this : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/load-image-from-existing-location-and.html

Answer (score 22):

I will just adapt Jim Dovey answer from here [Getting Image from URL Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933099/getting-image-from-url-objective-c) :

Synchronous version

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurl/mypic.jpg"]];
UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
```

Asynchronous version

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurl/mypic.jpg"]];
    if ( data == nil )
        return;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: data]];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/ytxO16A.png"];
```