# How can I display picture in app from a server?

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c

I am a new iOS developer. I need to know if the following is possible.

1. I will use objective C to dev my app (I am confortable with C and C++)
2. I have a Mysql Database. it will be stored on a network.
3. I need to get and post information between my app and my database. I have decided to use API rest json for that purpose. 
   I need to display pictures stored on the network/server in my app but I'm stuck as I can not find relevant information in google (as I am new to iOS development, I get lost). Could you please help me?

i do not have code to share as I am in the beginning of the development. I am just looking at information in order to know the cost of doing it.

best

jb

Comment: You can get image link/ image date by using API. To call API you can use NSUrlSessions. Link :https://www.raywenderlich.com/2392-cookbook-using-nsurlsession

Comment: I have forgotten to say that I do not want to download the picture on the app. I just want to display the picture. I do not know if my remark makes sense.

Comment: This link should be helpful [Getting Image from URL Objective C]
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/933159/5170595)

Comment: indeed, this is what I was looking for.